# Is there a term that describes the idea "I've already spent this much, I might as well pay a little more to get what I want"?

Tags: economic-terms

I came across this idea while looking to buy a house and I wondered if there was a term for it. The initial purchase options have a linear cost to value relationship. However, I'm tempted to make a larger purchase than planned because the additional value is proportionately much higher.

Simple Example:

- Option 1: Cost = 3, Value = 3
- Option 2: Cost = 5, Value = 5
- Option 3: Cost = 7, Value = 10

Comment: The title of the question seems to be referring to the sunk cost fallacy (https://thedecisionlab.com/biases/the-sunk-cost-fallacy) but the description makes me wonder if it's just a convex utility function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything but *utility maximization* here. With a quasilinear utility function, u = v - c, the first two options yield $u=0$ while the third one yields $u=3$.

Comment: Maybe the opportunity cost of spending 4 is >3

Answer (score 0):

From a Production Theory standpoint, I would argue that you have a convex "production function" (input = Cost, output = Value). In other words, the house purchase has *increasing returns to scale*.